# Application of Lenz's law to ideal transformer: how is there a magnetic flux within the iron core?

Tags: magnetic-fields, lenz-law

In an ideal transformer such as the one depicted below (switch is open), a sinusoidally changing magnetic field will be created by the primary coil. However, according to Lenz's law, this sinusoidally varying magnetic field is supposed to induce an emf that opposes this change, but then since the resistance is zero, wouldn't the net magnetic flux through the primary coil be zero?

[image]

source: myelectricalacedemy.com

Answer (score 2):

> according to Lenz's law, this sinusoidally varying magnetic field is supposed to induce an emf that opposes this change, but then since the resistance is zero, wouldn't the net magnetic flux through the primary coil be zero?

No. This could in theory happen to a superconducting loop without a voltage source - if the change of external magnetic flux is slow enough, net magnetic flux through such loop stays the same (in particular, can be zero), and net induced EMF $\mathscr{E}_i$ is zero in such a loop. Induced currents contribute exactly as much magnetic flux as needed for net induced EMF to stay zero. Formally, we can derive this result from Kirchhoff's second circuital law, which states that sum over all EMFs acting in the circuit equals $RI$:

$$
\sum_n \mathscr{E}_n = \mathscr{E}_i = RI.
$$

Since $R=0$ by assumption, for finite $I$ we get the prediction that

$$
\mathscr{E}_i = 0.
$$

In the case of a transformer winding connected to a voltage source, this does not happen, because there is the oscillating voltage source in the circuit, with its own EMF $\mathscr{E}_0$ acting on the current. Current is forced by this voltage source in the circuit, not by some external source of magnetic field. This means that net induced EMF in the circuit will exactly cancel EMF of this voltage source $\mathscr{E}_0$, so that current can stay finite. Formally,

$$
\sum_n \mathscr{E}_n = \mathscr{E}_0 + \mathscr{E}_i = RI \to 0~~~\text{for finite }I.
$$
$$
\mathscr{E}_i = -\mathscr{E}_0.
$$

So net induced EMF cannot be zero - instead, it is minus the emf of the voltage source. Consequently, magnetic flux is not constant in time.

Answer (score 1):

What has happened here is that you are double-counting. Lenz's law is not a separate stand alone law on its own. Lenz's law is simply the negative sign in Faraday's law. As stated in the Wikipedia article

> Lenz's law is **contained** in the rigorous treatment of Faraday's law of induction (the magnitude of EMF induced in a coil is proportional to the rate of change of the magnetic field), where it finds expression by the negative sign
> (emphasis added)

$$ \nabla \times \vec E = -\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t} $$ So once you have used Faraday's law to give you the EMF across your inductor then you have already applied Lenz's law to determine the sign of the EMF. You cannot then turn around and apply Lenz's law a second time to get rid of the EMF.

Comment: I think I see how I have double applied it now: the emf in the coils will already have a nonzero value before the current starts to change, so the change in flux becomes the change in flux due to the magnetic field of the current only, which also equals the change in magnetic flux due to the decay of the initial emf. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems right to me